Question discussion over questions one can ask on psychologySE

I have a question about my Psychology & Neuroscience Stack Exchange post: Life's psychological questions
Can one ask life's psychological questions like these:

Depression
Trauma

Etc. And seek support for it

You can also search meta for 'self-help' for more details.
